# Problem in PCA plot analysis

Tags: pca

I have generated these two PCA plots on Galaxy using two different GEO datasets, as a part of RNA-Seq analysis. In both, each group has several clusters. Also in the Obese vs Control dataset, the PC1 is very high 81%. So, according to my understanding none of the datasets are good to go.

Obese dataset:

[image]

T2D dataset:

[image]

My questions are:

1. How do we know if a PCA plot is good? What I have learnt from online tutorials is that the PC1 should not be very low or very high, a PC1 of 40-60% is good. Also, the samples should be neatly clustered into a single cluster.
2. Can I still take forward these two datasets by picking the closely clustered samples?
   Is there a statistical way to figure out which sub-clusters to choose for the next level of analysis? What is the minimum number of samples one should have in each group? Is it 2?

[[image]

[image]

Comment: You might find linear discriminant analysis worth a try. It will try to find a hyperplane which spans the two groups of data.